# Laravel Nova 4 customize layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-9, laravelcollective

Since Nova 4 has no blades anymore that you could publish, how could you approach customization the best in for example the head navbar next to the searchbar? I'd like to add a drop-down there but I don't know where to start or what to change?

In Nova 3 and earlier you had to publish the resources of nova and then you could add thing in your layout.blade.php.

Example
[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to override the Main Header Vue Component (just for info, located in: vendor/laravel/nova/resources/js/layouts/MainHeader.vue and etc...)

Can you try using the approach below? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/nova/how-to-override-a-nova-component?reply=672085

Comment: Hi Nikolay. After I change that .vue component, what should I "rebuild"? I am confused on that part...

Comment: You have to rebuild the tool and register the component with the same name as the component you want to overwrite.